# I want to split comma inside SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to split comma inside SQLite database.
I have two product_code type in one Product_code in one Product table.
can look at the picture Product table product_code column  have two prodcut type.How I can do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not have sqlite experience. so i want to ask this problem. I think anybody can help me.

Comment: I don't get the question. You have the single quote `'` and comma `,` in a your database field. So you want two entries by splitting with single quote and comma ?

Comment: I want to retrieve this two product code with single quote from one product_code column.

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.String split method accepts regular expression

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

You can use this patterns

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

yo can split productCode with `,`

```
String productCodes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_code"));  
String[] codes = productCodes.split(",");  

String code1 = codes[0]);
String code2 = codes[1]);



//for (String code: codes )  
// {  
//    System.out.println(code);  
// }
```

Comment: thanks.how to retrieve two product_code? eg.first product_code when customer buy and second product if customer buy frist product_code git free second product_code. I want to do this action.